# Integrating a trig function with a compound angle and raised to a power

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

I am trying to integrate:
sin^5(3x)
What I did is as follows:

sin^6(3x)/(-cos3x*3*6)

is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\sin^{2m+1}3x\,dx=\int\sin^{2m}3x\cdot\sin3x\,dx=\int(1-\cos^23x)^m\cdot\sin3x\,dx$$

Put $\cos3x=u$

Here $m=2$

Comment: Why is my way wrong?

Comment: @DanielFeinstein, first of all, it is easy to deal $\cos$ or $\sin$ in the numerator. What will be your substitution?